# i cannot solve this error in my code expected expression before ‘;’ token

Tags: c, syntax-error

hi i am more or less new to c and while i was learning how to use structures and unions i recived this error: "expected expression before ‘;’ token" i have been looking for the error for a long time but i can't find it. all i ask is a correction where needed in the following code.

i am using Gnu C Compiler on mac os x

```
#include <stdio.h>;
#include <stdlib.h>;

struct lista;
struct elemento;
union member{
  int i;
  struct lista * n;};

struct elemento{
  union member * v;
  struct elemento * n;};

struct lista{
  int len;
  struct elemento * n;};

void append(struct lista* a , union member * e);

int main(void){
  return 0;}

void append(struct lista * a , union member * e){
  struct elemento ** j= ((*a).n)*;                    /* error here */
  int c;
  for(c=0;c<(*a).len;c++){
    j=((**j).n)* ;}                                   /* error here */
  (*a).len++;
  *j=(struct elemento *)malloc(sizeof(struct elemento));
  (**j).v=e;}
```

it raises two errors in the  24th and the 28th line of code please help me

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what the 24th and 28th lines were.

Comment: What is `struct elemento ** j= ((*a).n)*;` supposed to do?

Comment: Oh my, where did you learn to write a code like that?

Comment: You can derference a pointer and access members via the `->` operator, no need to write code like `(*a).len` when you can write `a->len`.  @BasicWolf: He is learning :D.  It's pretty common for beginners to shove all the code they can into one line from what I have seen.  It goes away with experience.

Comment: Oh, and don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C Alberto.

Answer (score 5):

```
struct elemento ** j= ((*a).n)*;   // 24th line
```

Try this -

```
struct elemento ** j= & ((*a).n); // Note the removal of * and adding & symbol before.
```

Since `j` is pointer to a pointer, you need to add `&` symbol.

Comment: i am a stupid idiot , sorry if i posted the question ,i knew the & to retrive addresses but i forgot it, and confused with the * that indicates a pointer

Comment: @AlbertoPerrella: Hardly, just learning.  Everyone starts somewhere, and even the most experienced people miss simple things once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

```
void append(struct lista * a , union member * e){
  struct elemento ** j= ((*a).n)*;
```

You have a dangling asterisk there before the semicolon. Need to remove it:

```
void append(struct lista * a , union member * e){
  struct elemento ** j= ((*a).n);
```

Another occurrence of this problem is inside the for loop (thanks Dennis Meng).

---

Off topic: You don't need a semicolon after `#include`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: btw, there's another one in the for loop.

Comment: You've identified the cause of the error, but not, I think, the proper fix.  The type of `((*a).n)` is `struct elemento *`, and you're trying to assign it to `struct elemento **` -- which may compile but is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That star right before the semicolon is wrong. Not sure what you thought is good for, but you'll have to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem here

```
 for(c=0;c<(*a).len;c++) {
     j=((**j).n)* ;}
                ^
                ^
```

remove that `*`